# Replace some of Core Data records by app update

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, database-versioning

Let's say I use Core Data with entity 'Book' which has 'name', 'author', 'summary' and 'isFavorite' attributes. I prefill the Core Data and the only attribute which user can edit is 'isFavorite'.
In the next version of the app for some records I want to change/correct content of the 'summary' attribute but keep content of the 'name', 'author' and - most important - 'isFavorite'.
Can I somehow use Core Data versioning for that?
Or the Core Data versioning is only for model and has nothing to do with content and I should I look for some other solution?

Comment: Core Data versioning affects only the model, the content doesn't matter.

Comment: "the only attribute which user cannot edit is 'isFavorite'."  did you mean "the only attribute which user **can** edit is 'isFavorite'."?

Comment: to Jon Rose: of course. Thanx! Corrected.